# How to loop inside data frame with a condition?

Tags: r

I have a data.frame (df) which contains two columns (time, Result). I'm trying to loop inside the data frame based on the time and check the value of the Result to perform some condition. In other words, I want to go over the df from the beginning until the df$time value becomes 60. For each iteration I need to check the df$Result if it is greater than 100. I have done this by using subset, however, I'm wondering how to do it in different way..for example nested For loop.

I have created A MWE to illustrate the question;

```
 time<-seq(1,100,0.1)
 Result<-seq(1,991,1)
 df<-data.frame(time,Result)
 # I want to loop inside the df until the df$time=60
 # for each iteration I want to check the df$Result  if it's >100.
```

Here is my try to do it in nested :

```
 Df_time<-df$time
 Df_result<-df$Result
 x<-0

 for(i in Df_time){

     if(i > 60.0){

       for(i in Df_result){
          if(i >100){
            x<-x+1
           }
        }   


     }

  }

   cat("Total is ",x,"\n")
```

It doesn't seem right .. which I think related to the inner for loop as it will go over the whole range... Any suggestions?

Comment: In general I would avoid using the same running ndex `i` in nested loops (might lead to unwanted consequences)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sum(df$time > 60 & df$Result > 100)
```

will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

This should give you the count of the number of rows, I think that' what you're trying to add up as `x`

```
 dim(df[time < 60 & Result > 100,])[1]
```

Comment: this will not work with `data.frame` ;)  -- and if it does it would be due to mismanagement of environment variables

Comment: @RicardoSaporta, you're right. I haven't used data.frames in almost a year now so I've forgotten it little by little. What you say about environment variables is right because time and Result are being created first and I suspect that's what is being used to create the filter. Why don't you post the right way as an answer?

Comment: Note also that  `dim(·)[1]` is equivalent to `nrow(·)` so you'd better use the latter :D